# Select a hidden item using Selenium Python

Tags: python, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download pdfs in this page http://stivconsultasexternas.cnbv.gob.mx/ConsultaInformacionEmisoras.aspx. I want to select webdriverelement named "ctl00$DefaultPlaceholder$ComboFiltroPersonalizado" but it's hidden element and is not visible.

Here is my code. I appreciate any help.

```
import selenium as sel
driver = sel.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stivconsultasexternas.cnbv.gob.mx/ConsultaInformacionEmisoras.aspx")
elem=driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$DefaultPlaceholder$ComboFiltroPersonalizado")
```

I want to select "Ver todos" option.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to click on the corresponding `td` element that is clickable. Clicking on it makes the combobox opened:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_DefaultPlaceholder_ComboFiltroPersonalizado_B-1")
elem.click()
```

FYI, I've used *browser developer tools* to inspect which element lies under the `v` button:

[image]

---

Then, to select `Ver todos`, you can find it by ID, but before - [wait for it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stivconsultasexternas.cnbv.gob.mx/ConsultaInformacionEmisoras.aspx")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_DefaultPlaceholder_ComboFiltroPersonalizado_B-1")
elem.click()

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ctl00_DefaultPlaceholder_ComboFiltroPersonalizado_DDD_L_LBI3T0')))
elem.click()
```

Comment: Can you explain how you find the right element to click on to display the hidden element?

Comment: Thank you very much. if is not inconvenient for you cuan you explain me how to selct the option "Ver todos"? Anyway I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Nash sure, I've added a sample code that, first, opens up the dropdown, then, select `Ver todos` element.